# Disabling Diagnostic Tool key shortcut

Tags: sapui5

How can I disable UI5's diagnostic tool altogether in my application? It's triggered by key combination <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> which stands for letter **Ś**. I do not run my application with **`debug=true`**, so it should be `false` by default. Unfortunatelly I haven't found answer to my question in sapui5 documentation. I also tried put

```
sap.m.Support.off();
```

line, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Hi, isn't it triggered by *Ctrl*-Alt-Shift-S? That way, it shouldn't collide with the letter Ś

Comment: it's ALT + SHIFT + S for sure. Letter Ś appears in input control, but I want to block sapui5 diagnostic tool from appearing at the same time.

Comment: Which os / browser do you use?

Comment: Are you sure? I tried just Alt-Shift-S and that didn't work. Adding Ctrl to the mix dit id. Also according to http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/6e/c18e80b0ce47f290bc2645b0cc86e6/content.htm?frameset=/en/EF/1EB51B768D42708E3F1DE8EC0D5139/frameset.htm it should be Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S. Have you done some modification to your browser or OS shortcuts?

Comment: I use windows 8.1 and the newest release of google chrome. I know that it shouldn't work without crtl, but it does in my configuration and I consider it a big bug, that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code I think you can disable by setting the productive configuration property to true.

The configuration needs to appear before the bootstrap in the header.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window["sap-ui-config"] = {
    productive: true
  };
</script>
```

I've created a JSBIN example.

http://jsbin.com/waqiyimo/1/edit

Regards,
Jason

Comment: On your jsbin example the popup doesn't show up, but it doesn't fix problem in my applications. I set productive flag before loading sapui5 libraries, so I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Ok, after cleaning tomcat cache, setting productive flag really worked for me. Thanks!